# iOS - is View on top of view hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a map which is displayed to the user via a split view controller.

I need to be able to detect when the map is the front most view in the view hierarchy. The reason for this is; when the map region changes, it calls the delegate method:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated;
```

which is where I load my data from a remote source, and changing the device orientation appears to call this delegate method.

So my logic is, if the map is not the front most view (there could be a popover or modal displayed in front) then don't do the processing from the remote datasource, thus keeping the load on my servers to a minimum.

All modals and pop overs are currently displayed from the map views ViewController. I did think about doing it via use of a variable, however some of my popovers are displayed via connections build up in the storyboard rather than in code, so this isn't the ideal solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the property `presentedViewController` of `UIViewController` to check if the current view controller or one of its ancestors is presenting a view controller